# Excel | nested IF statements using dates

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to calculate the number of months in a given time range that fall within 2019.

My data looks like this:

[image]

I changed the format of my Start Date and End Date columns to "date". The "Duration in months" and output column have number formatting.

I approached it as follows:

1. If Start Date (year) < 2019 AND End date (year) = 2019, take the number of months between 1-1-2019 and the end date.
2. If start Date (year) < 2019 AND End date (year) > 2019, the number of months in 2019 = 12
3. If start Date (year) = 2019 AND End date (year) = 2019, take the number of months between Start Date and End date.
4. If start Date (year) = 2019 AND End date (year) > 2019, take the number of months between Start Date and 1-1-2020.
5. For all other cases, the number of months = 0.

I then followed the instructions from [this website](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/12/07/nested-if-excel-multiple-conditions/) for nested IF functions.

I came up with the following formula: (Edit: changed last datedif to 2020 instead of 2019)

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(A3)<2019;YEAR(C3)=2019);DATEDIF(DATE(2019;1;1);C3;"m");IF(AND(YEAR(A3)<2019;YEAR(C3)>2019);12;IF(AND(YEAR(A3)=2019;YEAR(C3)=2019);DATEDIF(A3;C3;"m");IF(AND(YEAR(A3)=2019;YEAR(C3)>2019); DATEDIF(A3;DATE(2020;1;1);m);0))))
```

For the first 4 rows, it correctly returns 12.
For row 7 and 8, however, it returns #NAME? .

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Much appreciated!

Amy

Comment: You deleted your last question too quickly.  I have a shorter version of your formula see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289520/non-adjecent-cells-as-input-to-array-function-min-and-isblank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the entire formula you have been consistent, apart from the last IF statement, where you went wrong within your `DATEDIF(` statement:

```
DATEDIF(A3;DATE(2019;1;1);m);0)
```

First of all you forgot to put `m` in quotes: `"m"`

Secondly you accidentally swapped the Date and Cell references, so it would have resolved `#NUM`. The full correct formula should be:

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(A7)<2019;YEAR(C7)=2019);DATEDIF(DATE(2019;1;1);C7;"m");IF(AND(YEAR(A7)<2019;YEAR(C7)>2019);12;IF(AND(YEAR(A7)=2019;YEAR(C7)=2019);DATEDIF(A7;C7;"m");IF(AND(YEAR(A7)=2019;YEAR(C7)>2019);DATEDIF(DATE(2019;1;1);A7;"m");0))))
```

Which will give you the result `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the following will give you the amount of full months between two dates. This works with your sample where your dates start on the first day of a month:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DATE(2019,ROW($1:$12),1)>=A2)*(DATE(2019,ROW($1:$12),1)<=C2))
```

Comment: Interesting approach. The expected output in the bottom 2 rows, however, is 4 instead of 8. (If it started in May 2019, only 4 months fall within 2019). Would this approach also work in that case?

Comment: Actually, you're right! It should be 8 in that case. I got confused myself. I still can't seem to get this formula working, however. Could you explain how it is supposed to work?

Comment: The idea is return an array of 1st days of each month in 2019 and check if they exists withing the range of the two given dates @AmyV. Can you tell me what about this you can't get to work? Have you started on your sample data?

Comment: @AmyV, have you changed the comma's for semi-colons?

Comment: I did put in semi-colons instead. It does not seem to make a difference. I get the "you entered too many arguments for this function" pop-up.

Comment: I see what went wrong, there is a comma in the `2019` value when I translated it automatically @AmyV, please see edit

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the quotes round the final "m" - try

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(A3)<2019;YEAR(C3)=2019);DATEDIF(DATE(2019;1;1);C3;"m");IF(AND(YEAR(A3)<2019;YEAR(C3)>2019);12;IF(AND(YEAR(A3)=2019;YEAR(C3)=2019);DATEDIF(A3;C3;"m");IF(AND(YEAR(A3)=2019;YEAR(C3)>2019); DATEDIF(A3;DATE(2019;1;1);"m");0))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. It does not seem to solve the issue, however. The error message only changed to #NUM! for the two final rows.